# Check if a cell in an ActiveRecord Array have been changed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm using PostgreSQL which supports arrays, which is very convenient. Sometimes I need to see if an element have been changed.

I know we can do this:

`MyActiveRecordArray.changed?`
`=> true`

But is there a way do this:

`MyActiveRecordArray[0].changed?`

Thank you for your answers and help!

Answer (score 1):

Although you can't do it directly, you may use the `changes` method:

```
model = Model.new
model.array_field = [1]
model.changed?
=> true
model.changes['array_field'] 
=> [[], [1]]
```

doc: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html#method-i-changes

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I come up with, thanks to your answer

```
changes_index = []  
old_array, new_array  = model.changes['array_field']  
new_array.each_with_index { |x, i| changes_index << i if x != old_array[i] }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can ask directly your ActiveRecord instance if a specific attribute has changed by using `attribute_name_changed?` method.

On your case:

```
MyModel.active_record_array_changed?
```

This would return `true` or `false` depending whether the specific attribute has changed.